# HTML "time" input format min:sec

Tags: html, input, time

Hopefully this would be a rather simple question.
I'm trying to force a "time" input tag to allow only minutes and seconds to enter.
The desired format would be MM:SS (without Hour and AM/PM).
So far the only way I've found was using the following code. However, Chrome still shows hours (12, grey and non accessible) and AM/PM (also gray, non accessible).
Any ideas? Is it possible to do what I'm trying to?
Thanks in advance!

```
<input type="time" step='1' min="00:00:01" max="00:10:00" name="duration" class="required">
```